# Angular2 - Get component html before template

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I have 2 components A and B defined this way:

**Component A:**

```
import { Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ElementRef} from 'angular2/angular2';
import ComponentB from ".'ComponentB";

@Component( {
    selector: 'component-a',
    directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES ],
    template: `
        <component-b>
            Inner text/html, whatever...
        </component-b>
    `
} )

export class ComponentA( {
    static parameters = [ [ ElementRef ] ];
    element:ElementRef;
    constructor( element:ElementRef ) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    afterViewInit():void {
    }
} )
```

**Component B:**

```
import { Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ElementRef} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component( {
    selector: 'component-b',
    directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES ],
    template: `
        <h1>{{innerContent}}</h1>
    `
} )

export class ComponentB( {
    static parameters = [ [ ElementRef ] ];
    element:ElementRef;
    innerContent:string;

    constructor( element:ElementRef ) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    afterViewInit():void {
    }
} )
```

What i want to accomplish is to use the content between the `<component-b>` tag in Component A template to set the variable `innerContent` of ComponentB.

I have tried to use `this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML` inside `afterViewInit` of ComponentB class, but it gets the innerHTML of the template variable, not of the parent one.

Restrictions: 
Use of custom attributes in the component using @Inputs/@Outputs is not an option.
**e.g.**

```
    <component-b [innerContent]="Inner text/html, whatever...">
    </component-b>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ComponentB template, put this:

```
template: `
    <h1><ng-content></ng-content></h1>
`
```